# Angular formulario submit

Tags: html, angularjs

Pessoal estou usando o metronic com angular e tenho o controller tudo certo, porem tentei criar uma função que exibe oq o usuario digitou em um campo em um alert (futuramente irei filtrar)...

arquivo HTML :

```js
angular.module('App').controller('UserProfileController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        App.initAjax(); // initialize core components
        Layout.setSidebarMenuActiveLink('set', $('#sidebar_menu_link_profile')); // set profile link active in sidebar menu
        $scope.form.txt;
    });

    // set sidebar closed and body solid layout mode
    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = true;
    $rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = true;

    $scope.Submit = function() {
       alert($scope.form.txt);
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="#" ng-submit="Submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.txt" placeholder="John" class="form-control" /> </div>
        <div class="margiv-top-10">
        <a input type="submit" id="submit"  ngClick="Submit()"  class="btn green-haze"> Save Changes </a>

    </div>
</form>
```

Alguem sabe como arrumar ?
Obg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem 2 problemas, e são no seu html:

1. `ng-submit="Submit()"` na tag `<form>`, mas seu form não tem um `button type="submit"` (os atributos `type` e `input` [não existem em tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) `<a>` )
2. `ngClick` em sua tag `<a>`, o certo é: `ng-click`

Abaixo, o código html modificado, eu fiz outras pequenas correções que melhoram o funcionamento do html. Veja se funciona agora.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="" name="form_user_info">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input id="first_name" type="text" ng-model="form.txt" placeholder="John" class="form-control" /> </div>
        <div class="margiv-top-10">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submit" ng-click="Submit()" class="btn green-haze"> Save Changes </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Deu certo... muito obrigado ...